# Maintaining order of processing with multiple instances

Tags: c#, .net, azure, redis, azureservicebus

SenderApp is sending values to service bus queue and on the other end we have two receiver instances.
**Requirement is that we only save values that have changed to db** (all incoming values are first saved to redis cache where comparison happens).

SenderApp sends three values in following order to queue: (1, 2, 1).
-----1---2---1------------------------>

Now the values go in queue with FIFO method and on the other end of queue we have two instances of receiver application.
This is where it gets interesting.
Lets say due to latency or some other factor second receiver instance is slow to process the value(2) and ends up saving it to database last from all three values.
So it should be something like this:

**Receiver instance #1**
---------------------1---1------------>

**Receiver instance #2**
-----------------------------2-------->

Now we have a problem. Instance one is comparing the second sent value which is 1 against the first value which is also 1 and it doesn't get saved to database. Values that are sent to service bus queue have timestamps attached to them.

Also it needs to be fairly scalable solution.
All ideas are welcome, maybe levarage the redis cache, maybe service bus sessions?

Edit:
**For more clarification:**
Each incoming message has device id and value attached to it so we must not save any consecutive duplicate values for that specific device.
So for example we have two incoming messages from the same device.
First incoming message has a value 1 with device id 999 (we must save it).
But now the next incoming message also has value 1 and device id 999.
So that would be consecutive duplicate and we must not save it.
Also what makes this problem difficult is that we also can not save values directly on sender side.

**Explanatory graph of the general flow below:**
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I think you need to think through your explanation more. It seems trivial to me - just save every value.

Comment: Wouldn't it help if you would chain those events? Instance 1 processes the event, adds new event to another queue, then the next instance does something, adds again ... and so on. If you are not able to do parallel processing, just do sequential

Comment: @Enigmativity I have added a explanatory drawing of the general flow and what I need to achive.

Comment: @JulianHüppauff Why would instance 1 after processing the event add it to another queue? Goal is to save it to database.
I have updated my post with more information. Maybe I didn't explain it good enough, sorry.

Comment: Competing consumers on a regular queue will interfere with your requirements. Have you looked into Message Sessions? In this case a session per device would be appropriate and insure messages are processed in the order they were sent.

Comment: @SeanFeldman Yes, that is very good idea!
I will give it a go and now I have to think how can i implement it as such that receivers are able to scale out at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Competing consumers (receivers) will contradict the requirement to handle messages in the order they were sent. To adhere to the in-order processing, the Azure Service Bus [message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) feature could help. A single receiver only processes a session at any time; there's no processing by multiple receivers. This eliminates the chance of having messages from the same source processed in parallel and out of order. This is still a scalable approach as receivers can handle different sessions. If messages for a given session arrive after some time, the session processing would be picked up by any competing receivers.

In this scenario, where a uniquely identifiable device emits messages, the device ID could be used as a session ID.

Worth noting that each receiver can handle multiple sessions in parallel, not just a single session. That way, the solution can scale out and up, depending on the compute used and complexity of the code executed per message.